# How to access the image using path in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have to use an image that is stored in the directory uploaded/images in Html/javascript file using Flask.

```
<img id="img" src= "">
<h1 id="file_path" style="visibility:hidden">{{ file_path }}</h1>
```

and js

```
var file_path = "../uploaded/images/" + document.getElementById("file_path").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src",file_path)
```

And the directory structure looks like this:

predict.html contains those codes (above).

The image to be shown is inside uploaded/images.

home.py is the flask app.

[image]

Comment: You should put the images in the static folder. Follow whatever tutorial on Youtube.

Comment: You can see the the folder is named uploaded, this would imply it's untrusted content. You really only want to put content you trust into the static dir.

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of:
[What is the correct way to serve/access media files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69769260/18020941)

Accepting uploaded media files locally is

- Very process-intensive.
- Dangerous, security-wise

Please make sure to put in enough checks to validate the content, and if you can, serve them off-site, on a different domain.